# bash read split file after string

Tags: bash, file, split

I am tring to create one shell script to split text files after one specific STRING.

```
Line of text 
Line of text 
STRING
Line of text 
Line of text
```

I pretend to have 2 files, one from begining to STRING and other with STRING to end contents.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '1,/STRING/p' inputfile > file1
sed -n '/STRING/,$p' inputfile > file2
```

With awk:

```
awk '/STRING/{flag=1;print>"file1"}
    flag {print>"file2";next}
    {print>"file1"}
' inputfile
```

If you need the line to contain the exact word `STRING` and nothing more, then just substitute `STRING` for `^STRING$` in the scripts above.

---

If you don't want `STRING` to be present in first file,

```
awk '/STRING/{flag=1}
    flag {print>"file2";next}
    {print>"file1"}
' inputfile
```

Comment: thanks for reply
it doesn't work, on first option it includes the line containing STRING and the second gives one error.

Comment: @SergioPeres You're welcome. Well, then you should make clear in your question that you don't want `STRING` in the first file. And what error do you get with the `awk`? I tested it with both `mawk` and `gawk`, both work.

Comment: sorry I don't refer it as I suposed to be implicit, well I have files with lots of text and I want to split them after one string. I pretend to build two files one from the first line to the last before string and the other with the rest.